# Thymeleaf finds CSS and JS file, but doesn't interpret them. Why?

Tags: javascript, css, spring-mvc, resources, thymeleaf

My project has the following structure:

```
webapps/
    assets/
        css/
        img/
        js/
    WEB-INF/
        html/
            fragments/
                common.html
                default.html
                header.html
                sidebar.html
        home/
            homeNotSignedIn.html
            homeSignedIn.html   
        login.html
```

Om my `Application.java` I have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.g.appName")
public class AppnameConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// ... several beans

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/css/**","/js/**","/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/","/js/","/img/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

When I run the application, my landing page `homeNotSignedIn.html` is shown but no CSS or JS are loaded by Thymeleaf.

When I right click and select view page source, all links are there, correctly formatted like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/applicationName/assets/css/animate.min.css" />
```

But if I try to call directly this css, I'm redirected to the login page and can't access the file. I have tried *as per* someone's suggestion to rename html foldel to templates and assets folder to static (and to all the necessary changes on the pages). Same result.

What really strikes me as odd is that this project is almost an *ipsis literis* copy of another project I work on and everything is resolved beautifully.

I'm on the verge of going insane on this one... Please help me out! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Dispatcher configured to handle the request?
You may need something similar to this in your onStartup:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    ........


    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new   AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(AppnameConfiguration .class);
}
```

Comment: I don't have anything like it... Mainly because I don't have it on the other working project.

Comment: May you should try changin your <link> for something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/assets/css/animate.min.css}" />`

and in your AppNameConfiguration:
`if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/assets/**")) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets/");
  }`